# navigator.getBattery() does not exist on type Navigator

Tags: javascript, typescript, batterymanager

I'm trying a custom React hook called `useBattery` to access the battery status but TypeScript says that `getBattery()` does not exist on type `Navigator`:

[image]

Based on the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/BatteryManager) the interface name is `BatteryManager` but I did not find this interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because this is not standardized, and also not supported by all browsers, the Typescript team decided that it should not be implemented.

For background see here: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15314

You can probably get around this by casting `navigator` to `any` and then calling the required functions, but you'll have to make it robust in case the browser does not support it.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me in plain vanilla JS...

```
var Bat=[];

navigator.getBattery().then(function(battery){

 if(isNaN(battery.level)){Bat[0]='?';} else {Bat[0]=battery.level;}

 Bat[1]=battery.charging;

 Bat[2]=battery.chargingTime;

 Bat[3]=battery.dischargingTime;    

});
```

NB: Array elements 0..3 hold the various values.

Comment: Welcome @PassingThru to SO. Yes, but my code is on TypeScript not JavaScript ( vanilla )

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the getBattery is not part of the [TS Navigator interface](https://microsoft.github.io/PowerBI-JavaScript/interfaces/_node_modules_typedoc_node_modules_typescript_lib_lib_dom_d_.navigator.html), it is likely due to it not being a [browser standard](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/getBattery#browser_compatibility).

You may try the following to execute the function anyway tho you might still get some warning

```
type NavigatorKey = keyof typeof navigator;
const key = 'getBattery' as NavigatorKey;
console.log(await navigator[key]())
```